# Angular 5 : Data service, loading initial values

Tags: angular, angular5

I load financial transactions into a MySQL database and use a PHP restful API and angular 5 frontend to generate reports.  Using dropdowns, users can select the beginning and ending dates and run reports for different periods.  I created a service “DateService” that starts with two initial values (thismo and lastmo) and assigns them to the date variables (datev and datevb).

```
private datevSource = new BehaviorSubject <string> (this.thismo);
datev = this.datevSource.asObservable();
private datevbSource = new BehaviorSubject <string> (this.lastmo);
datevb = this.datevbSource.asObservable();
```

datev (end date) and datevb (beginning date) are used to query the database to generate the reports.  The user can change these dates as often as they like and the values are maintained in DateService. If they navigate to a different report, the last selected values are maintained in the DateService.They can also reset the values to the default (thismo & lastmo).

```
setDates(datevar, datevarb) {
    this.datev = datevar;
    this.datevb = datevarb;
    }
reDate() {
   this.datevSource.next(this.thismo);
   this.datevbSource.next(this.lastmo);
   }
```

Thismo and lastmo don’t change when the user generates reports. The values are currently hardcoded and I change them in the service and rebuilt/upload the app whenever the database is updated (usually once a month).  It doesn’t seem like I should be rebuilding the app just to change these two variables.

I created a new table in the database that houses those values and would like hit the API once to store thismo and lastmo when the user accesses the application.  How can I change my datevSource to check if thismo has been loaded from the API, load if it hasn’t and then pass the value like normal?  I tried creating a new variable (firstrun = 0) and incrementing it when running a function (loadGlobals), but the other functions that query the database run before loadGlobals finishes.

I could cheat and load thismo from the database every time, but I am trying to avoid hitting the API every time someone navigates to a new page.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, its not very clear what you're asking. You just want to get the values on `thismo` and `lastmo` dynamically? What should the values of `thismo` and `lastmo` actually be?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 2 values that don't change often.

You want to get them from an API but don't want to call it every time.

This is a simple caching issue.

There are various ways of approaching caching in an Angular app. You could cache the response from the API in a service. If the service has already got the API response then return the previously fetched values. Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ThismoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private thismo 

  public getThismo(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.thismo == null) {
      return this.http.get('/thismo').pipe(
        map(response => response.thismo),
        tap(thismo => this.thismo = thismo)
      )
    } else {
      return of(this.thismo)
    }   
  }
}
```

A more professional approach would be to use a global Redux-based store solution such as [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform). The store can be accessed at any time from anywhere and is great for caching. You could introduce logic to cache for 1 day and then fetch from the API once a day. If you are going to use ngrx, good RxJs skills are very useful.

Sadly, ngrx tutorials are generally rubbish - if you can afford it this is a great ngrx course on Udemy - https://www.udemy.com/ngrx-course/learn/v4/content